# error C2059: syntax error: '}'

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I'm writing a blackjack program. I created the class card which contains two strings and an integer. 'dealer' is a vector of class 'card', 'dtotal' and 'deckplace' are both integers. 'display()' is a function that prints the cards, suits, and totals. The error occurs in the line above "else if (total>16)".

```
void dealerTurn()
{
    if (dtotal<17)
    {
        do while (dtotal<17)
        {
            dealer.pop_back(deck[deckplace]);
            deckplace = deckplace+1;

            for (y=0;y<dealer.size();y++)
            {
                if (dealer[y].name=="A" && dtotal>21)
                {
                    dealer[y].value = 1;
                    dtotal = 0;
                    for (z=0;z<dealer.size();z++)
                        dtotal = dtotal + dealer[z].value;
                }
            }

            display();

            if (dtotal>21)
            {
                cout << endl << "-----DEALER BUSTED!-----" << endl << endl;
                dtotal = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (total>16)
    {
        display();
    }
    result();
}
```

Comment: `do while` ??????????????????

Comment: I feel a _little_ harsh doing this, but -1 for no research, because your C++ book did _not_ teach you `do while (X) { Y }`. which means you made it up and didn't look into it when it failed.

Comment: I didn't learn C++ from a book. I didn't think that the do loop would've caused that syntax. I researched other examples of this syntax error before posting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no such thing as `do while`. It is either `while (__condition__) { __statements__ }` or `do { __statements__ } while (__condition__);`.

Comment: int i(0);
  while(i++<5) ;
     do ; while (i++<10) ;  is OK. The {} are "optional".